# Bootstrap modal with URL rewriting

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, url-rewriting, bootstrap-modal

The structure of my pages is:

- `Page1.aspx`
- `Page2.aspx`
- `Page3.aspx`

With URL rewriting I have this struture:

- `Folder1/Page1`
- `Folder1/Page2`
- `Page3`

If I put a modal inside `Page3.aspx`, the modal works perfectly.

If I instead put a modal inside `Page1.aspx` or `Page2.aspx`, the modal doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<img src="../images/RecuperoDati/Brochure1.jpg" class="img-responsive"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal1"/>

....

 <!-- Modal 1-->
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">rftyguhij</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body center">
         <img src="../images/RecuperoDati/Brochure1.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa. Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione. È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato. Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I read the HTML with the browser, the `id` is `Modal1`.  So what Is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @nick_w: When I click on the Modal trigger, the modal doesn't show.

Comment: Are your CSS files loaded correctly in the Url-rewritten pages?

Comment: @nick_w: yes, they're loaded correclty.

Comment: have you checked the html for the page1 & 2 and made sure the bootstrap.js and css references are correct?

Comment: How are you loading bootstrap? I mean could you show the script which is loading bootstrap.js?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say when you've only given some of the code, but my guess is you URL rewriting is changing the path you need to use for `bootstrap.js`.

E.g. in Page3 if your path to the JS is `./js/bootstrap.js` then in Page1, which becomes Folder1/Page1, you would need `../js/bootstrap.js` instead.